# Handle Change of FormControl React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is the example of Textarea where i could not able to set the state value in form-control,..
i could not able to save the state value ,

```
<Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
   <Form.Control className="textarea" 
              value={selectDesc} 
              as="textarea"
              rows={7} 
              onChange={(event)=>setSelectDesc(event.target.value)}>
  </Form.Control> </Form.Group>
```

[outout of the screen ,..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgZhb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example on how you could achieve this (I used an `<input>` tag but this would have the same result for a `<Form />` from react-bootstrap):

```js
import { useState } from "react"; // import useState

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(""); // useState hook

  // handle change event
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
    setName(e.target.value); // set name to e.target.value (event)
  };

  // render
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={name} type="text" onChange={handleChange}></input>
      <p>{name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I made a handler function to make the code a bit cleaner, don't forget to prevent the default action and set the value.

This would be the result using *react-bootstrap*

```js
import { useState } from "react"; // import useState
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(""); // useState hook

  // handle change event
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
    setName(e.target.value); // set name to e.target.value (event)
  };

  // render
  return (
    <div>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Control
            value={name}
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
      <p>{name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check out my sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-joliot-jr7q4?file=/src/App.js:0-469)